# File status 39 in VSAM KSDS file

Tags: file, cobol, mainframe, jcl, vsam

Vsam file creation -

```
//VSAMKSDS JOB CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=A,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),PRTY=15,    
//             NOTIFY=&SYSUID                                
//STEP10 EXEC PGM=IDCAMS                                     
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                       
//SYSIN DD *                                                 
        DEFINE CLUSTER(                 -                    
                  NAME(RAHUL.KSDS.FILE) -                    
                  INDEXED               -                    
                  KEYS(05 1)            -                    
                  RECSZ(35 35)          -                    
                  FREESPACE(10 20)      -                    
                  TRACKS(50 30)         -                    
                  CISZ(8192)            -                    
                  VOLUME(ZASYS1))                            
/*
```

Records in file -

```
    RBA          Len     1<==5>..10....5...20....5...30....5..
      0           35     12543rajjd jdhdjd        9876553     
     35           35     53221dfdffd jhsfhd       9778785
```

Getting error -

---

KSDSFL OPEN STATUS 39
KSDSFL CLOSE STATUS 42

---

My Cobol Program:-

```
 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.              
 PROGRAM-ID. KSDSPROG.                 
 ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                 
 INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.                 
 FILE-CONTROL.                         
     SELECT KSDSFL ASSIGN TO INFLDD    
     ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED           
     ACCESS MODE IS RANDOM             
     RECORD KEY IS EMP-ID              
     FILE STATUS IS RTCODE.            
 DATA DIVISION.                        
 FILE SECTION.                         
 FD KSDSFL.                            
 01 KSDSFL-REC.                        
    05 EMP-ID      PIC X(05).          
    05 EMP-DESC    PIC X(30).          
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                      
01 RTCODE         PIC X(02).                  
01 REC-OUT        PIC X(35).                  
PROCEDURE DIVISION.                           
    OPEN INPUT KSDSFL.                        
    DISPLAY 'KSDSFL OPEN STATUS ' RTCODE.     
    MOVE '12345' TO EMP-ID                    
    READ KSDSFL RECORD INTO REC-OUT           
    KEY IS EMP-ID                             
    INVALID KEY                               
    DISPLAY 'KEY IS INVALID'                  
    NOT INVALID KEY                           
    DISPLAY 'KEY IS VALID'                    
    END-READ.                                 
    CLOSE KSDSFL.                             
    DISPLAY 'KSDSFL CLOSE STATUS ' RTCODE.    
    STOP RUN.
```

No idea why I am getting the data mismatch issue. Program is compiling successfully but on running getting file-status 39.
all field records are matched but still Issue not resolved. please help me to resolve it.

Comment: Your key starts in *position* 1 but the second parameter to `KEYS` is an *offset*. Have you tried `KEYS(05 0)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data you provided shows a record length of 37.  It should be 35.

*I modified the question section for the record to make it code so there was a fixed width font as it was confusing me where the record lines up.  If I made an error please correct.*

Your key in the `FD` section (`EMP-ID`)starts in offset 0; it should be offset 1.

```
 FILE SECTION.                         
 FD KSDSFL.                            
 01 KSDSFL-REC.                        
    05 EMP-ID      PIC X(05).          
    05 EMP-DESC    PIC X(30).
```

change to

```
 FILE SECTION.                         
 FD KSDSFL.                            
 01 KSDSFL-REC.                        
    05 FILLER      PIC X.
    05 EMP-ID      PIC X(05).          
    05 EMP-DESC    PIC X(29).
```

Comment: Created new KSDS file with keys (5 0). it working fine now.

Comment: Very good, those dang offsets where sometimes 0 is the first and others where 1 is the first … good luck

Comment: To make sure the question is correctly presented ... should the record format above be changed?

From: 
    RBA          Len     1<==5>..10.

To:
    RBA          Len     <===>...10.

?